# Django Unable to Find reverse() URL

Tags: django, function, authentication, reverse

I have the following URLConf setup:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('myapp.views',
    url(r'^$', 'index', name="home"),
    url(r'^login$', 'login'),
)
```

So far in my views, I have this:

```
def index(request):
    """Displays paginated message views"""
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("myapp.views.login"))

def login(request):
    """Displays login screen"""
    return render_to_response('myapp/login.html', {
            "title": "Login"
    })
```

The problem arises when I try to go to the login page. Django seems to be unable to find my URL.

Going to the url http://localhost:8000/login, I receive the following error:

> Page not found (404)
>   Request Method: GET Request
>   URL: http://localhost:8000/login
>   'login' could not be found 
>   You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django
>   settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a
>   standard 404 page.

It seems that even though I am using the reverse function to find Django's own recommended URL based on my URLConf, it is still unable to find its own URL!

Any ideas?

EDIT: 
I need to clarify somethings: The problem is not that Django is unable to figure out the correct URL, it is that once that URL is loaded, Django is unable to find the view associated with that.

Comment: Your title is misleading. You would only use the reverse when you view the index (/). FYI what does that give you?

Comment: I have edited the title a bit, please read the clarified post near the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the error was caused by me changing the STATIC_URL variable in my settings.py file. Changing that back to "/static/" made everything work.

Answer (score 0):

can you please put name attribute to your url like this
url(r'^$', 'index', name="home"),

then call reverse with this name

examples

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^archive/(\d{4})/$', archive, name="full-archive"),
    url(r'^archive-summary/(\d{4})/$', archive, {'summary': True}, "arch-summary"),
)

from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def myview(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('arch-summary', args=[1945]))

Comment: The problem is not that reverse doesn't give the intended URL, it is that when that URL is requested, I get a Page Not Found error.